# Boost.Python id of object

Tags: python, boost-python

How do I get the id of a python object in boost python.  I was hoping for something like

```
boost::python::obj = ...;
int id = boost::python::id(obj);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Python [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id), in CPython, the value returned is the address of the object. So, if you're looking for something similar in Boost Python:

```
boost::python::api::object obj = ...;
long id = static_cast<long>(obj.ptr());
```

A cursory glance in the source; the built-in `id` function's implementation (I'm looking at 2.6.4) is merely:

```
static PyObject *
builtin_id(PyObject *self, PyObject *v)
{
    return PyLong_FromVoidPtr(v);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is good enough for me.  I just needed something that I could hash quickly, and I can hash the `ptr()`.